# Bring forward Excel Worksheet opened from within Intranet page

Tags: excel, vba

A page labeled "Forms" in our Intranet contains call buttons to a large number of Excel applications.  When a user selects one, Windows displays the panel asking what you wish to do with the file, to which the user clicks on Open.  The file opens but stays behind the Intranet html page, thus making necessary to click the x-out to close the Intranet and render the Worksheet visible.  Is there any way to have the worksheet come forward or sending the Intranet backwards?  New users, unaware of the x-out step, wait forever and get frustrated when the desired Excel app did not show up as expected.

Comment: What browser are you using?  Let me guess.  Internet Explorer?

Comment: Each workbook have open event, so try to close your allmighty Internet Explorer in here.